# Can we able to hide/show standard button('Edit Opportunity Split' button) of opportunity split which is in related lists of opportunity.?

Tags: object, salesforce, admin, apex

I was trying to hide/show "Edit Opportunity Split" standard button which is in the Opportunity related list under Opportunity Split based on the role. I couldn't able to able to find out where it is exactly available? Can I able to do hide/show standard button?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and show buttons by editing layouts. setup --> customize--> pick the object where the button is --> layouts--> edit then add or remove the button.